# How can we disable this "Can one of the admins verify this patch? "on the GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin?

Tags: github, jenkins-plugins

When triggering a job on  a pull request this comment "Can one of the admins verify this patch?" is automatically added to the pull request how can we disable this on the GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible workaround is to add the username of anyone you want to be allowed to trigger the job to the `Admin List` within the GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin section of Build Triggers in your Jenkins job.

Also, if the repository is part of a GitHub organization you can simply add your organization name to the `List of organizations.` section of the plugin configuration which will allow all members in the organization to be whitelisted and allowed to trigger jobs.

Comment: Thanks Brandon I tried to add the users to admin list GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin section using their username but it did not make a different again when a pull request was trigged by that user the comment "Can one of the admins verify this patch?" was automatically generated again..WIll try the second option organization might help... thank you!

Comment: @arthi I've seen this happen a few times as well and have found the organization solution to work best. You can also directly whitelist usernames outside of the organization from the configuration panel within each job.

Comment: I added organization name on the job but it made no difference. Is there a specify way to add the organization name? Example : https://github.com/Software(this is organization name)/reponame.. So I added Software in the advance section "List of organizations. Their members will be whitelisted" of pull request builder. Do I need to add anything in the GitHub hook that I created?

Comment: @arthi Just placing the organization name in that section worked for me.

Comment: alright thanks @Brandon. I'm switching blue ocean pull request trigger as this plugin seems unsafe per this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

Comment: Another guide: https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs-build/issues/21#issuecomment-294868940

Answer (score 2):

I simply went on the plugin config and modified the phrase to the empty string.

- On the main server config page find "GitHub Pull Request Builder"
- Click on **"Advanced..."** button underneath
- Find box underneath: **"Request for testing phrase"**
- Delete the contents of the box
- Save the config

Comment: Cheers Jeremy, this is an easier way without having to change Admin Lists.